# Have set up a file server. How to make it accessible from anywhere?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, xubuntu, ftp

I have installed xubuntu and made it a file server in my college using this guide.
[How to build your own file server](http://www.intac.net/build-your-own-server/)

Okay I am pretty new to these things, but I want to know a few things?

1) I understand the machine is in my college and have a local static IP assigned to it. So how can I access that machine from anywhere else outside? (Port forwarding? But how to do that?)

2) Installed proftpd on it, but have no idea on how to use it?

3) How can I access that machine remotely? Right now I am only getting shell access using putty.

4) How can I make the most out of it? Have a dedicated 54 MBps line for this machine.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the college reconfigures their router to port forward to your computer it cannot be done. The best you can do is host the files on a server outside the college and sync files between that computer and yours

Comment: If the college agrees to do that, how can I possibly do that?

Comment: I can tell you now the college will not agree, sorry to tell you that, I'm a network admin and i would not allow it on my network, so I doubt the college will

Comment: They have agreed! :)

Comment: It seems generalizing from one IT department to all IT departments doesn't always work. :) @neo1691 They should have forwarded the port or given you instructions for what to do. Did they? Should we close this as *too localized*?

Comment: The thing is that they also don't know exactly how to do port fordwarding. They do have a linksys router. Hopefully I'll do that soon